# Nested if else, which one is it out of the options:

Tags: c++, nested

[image]

How is this called :

- if else
- if and if else
- if or if else
- if
- none of the above

Comment: We're not going to do your homework for you. What do you think the answer is? Explain why, and if you're wrong, we'll help you understand why.

Comment: I believe "it's if or if else" but a friend of mine says it's if and if else but he isn't sure either. So it's a doubt between those two. I couldn't find anything on google. Everywhere it just says nested if else.

Comment: Why don't you try writing actual C++ code to implement it?

Comment: I know how to write it. It's just in theory what does that chart represent.
Is it if or if else or if and if else

Comment: I'm not even sure I understand the choices. `and` and `or` would be used in the test expressions, they're not part of `if/else`.

Comment: Yes,I'm confused too. Couldn't find anywhere the answer to that question and yet it could appear on my pretest.

Answer (score 1):

There is an `if-else` and an `if` :

```
if (n > 0) {
    if ((n % 3) == 0) {
        cout << "The number is positive and divisible by 3\n"; 
    }
}
else {
    cout << "The number is zero or negative \n";
}
//continue...
```

So looking at the possible answers, it's either the second one or the last one, depending if the order of the english text matters or not.  The wording is unfortunate and ambiguous

Reasoning by elimination brings us to the same conclusions:

- It definitively can't be just `if` nor `if-else` as there are 3 different branches with different outcomes.
- It can't be `if or if-else`,  because the two conditions in the diagramme are in cascade. This means clearly that the outcome depends of the two conditions (and), and not just one (or).

**Edit:** But if I'd have to answer in an exam, I'd say second answer because I see an `if { and if } else` : the ambguity of the english sentence gives me the right to understand that the `else` of the `if and if else` could be associated with the first if an not necessarily the second.

Comment: I'm sorry. I just need an answer of the possible answers. I know how to write code for a nested if else, I don't need code. Just how is that called other than nested if else.

Comment: The point was to show you what the chart looks like in code so YOU can decide which of the available answers best matches it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, exactly ! Thanks !  But Claire's insitance forced me to think about ambiguity of associativity in the english language, which is much more fuzzy and flexible than in the C++ grammar and hence opens the door for argumentation ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The graphic represents an `if-else` and an `if`.  They do not appear in that particular order in the list of answers, so I would choose **if and if else** only if that answer is allowed to be ambiguous and the order is not important, otherwise I would choose **none of the above** instead.

Comment: :-)  So now Claire has to choose between the possible interpretations ;-)

Comment: Clairvoyance needs to decide why (s)he is taking a test that has unclear questions and ambiguous answers to begin with!  Whoever wrote that test needs a refresher on proper human language!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone needs to know this here it is :

- IF AND IF ELSE

Why? Because when a new if statement comes after an if statement is true then it's called if and if else.

Otherwise if there was a new if statement on the left side where it's false it would be if or if else.

Thank you all.